# Translating a div from english to Arabic language using google translate api in asp mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-api

I am working on a small project in which i have two divs, one for `English` and another one for `Arabic`.
I have created this project but the problem is that I am not getting the translation from `English to Arabic`, below is the code
I have tried. I don`t know what I am doing wrong any help would be appreciated thanks.

**Edit: my request is successfully going to the google but every time error body is executing in the ajax**

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="sourceText">Hello world</div>
    <div id="translation"></div>
    <script>
        var sourceText = escape(document.getElementById("sourceText").innerHTML);
        var source = "https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=AIzaSyBBsdXcsCLjSex4-9EReA_MqsBFrLrkwm4&source=en&target=ar&callback=translateText&q=";
        $.ajax({
            url: source + encodeURIComponent(sourceText),
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.data.translations[0].translatedText);
                        $('#translation').html(data.data.translations[0].translatedText);    
                },

            error: function(x, e) {
                alert('Error occured while translating the text');
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you be more specific what goed wrong. does the google api alow you to translate because i got an error there

Comment: @Rickert yes my request successfully going to the google but every time error body in the ajax body executing

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: @Rickert uncaught reference error: `translateText is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't had the callback function defined:

```
var sourceText = escape(document.getElementById("sourceText").innerHTML);
var source = "https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=AIzaSyBBsdXcsCLjSex4-9EReA_MqsBFrLrkwm4&source=en&target=ar&callback=translateText&q=";
$.ajax({
    url: source + encodeURIComponent(sourceText),
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonpCallback: "translateText",
    async: false,
    error: function(x, e) {
        alert('Error occured while translating the text');
    }
});

function translateText(data){
    alert();
}
```

here a jsfiddle:
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jt0gqLbo/)

Comment: i did not get your answer properly how to receive translated text?

Comment: In my example you see your function with the TranslateText function. thats a callback function with data you get from Google. so if you add console.log(data) in tje translateText function you see the data you get from the ajax call.. from there on you have to check and pu the data in the right place

Comment: now i get from google `There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if request from this IP or referer should be allowed.`

Comment: So it works.. well the code itself.. but your api key is incorrect. so you have to give google the right apikey and you have to process the data and your done :)

Comment: Thanks for your contributions now i am getting  `Daily Limit Exceed` while only 60+ request have been made

Comment: maybe others tried it here or the limit of google is verry low. maybe try a new key.